# how to maintain the intent in Android?

Tags: android

I have three Activities like and start this sequence A -> B -> c->
Activity 'A' here i have to get the JSON data from server and Activity 'B' start from Activity 'A'.Activity 'C' start from Activity 'B'

But the problem is when comeback to  Activity 'B' from Activity 'c' again start to download the JSON data from server and its get so long time to start the activity.How to solve this issues. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: what u want?? on Back press of Activity C you dont want to load json data on Activity B?? Please Give Brief problem what u want to do

Comment: Sorry for my Mistack . onBackPress of Activity B , dont want to load json data on Activity A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You can use like this

```
<activity 
android:name=".MainTabActivity"
android:launchMode="singleTask" 
android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" 
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
</activity>
```

For Better Undersatnding Use [This TUTORIAL](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/6/16/android-understanding-activity-launchmode)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your manifest.xml, inside every activity tag add this one like below.Hope it might help.

```
<activity ..
  android:launchMode= "singleInstance" />
```

Include this in  every activity and check.Your pages wont be loading again hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent objEvent) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, objEvent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        ActivityB.Finish();
    }
```

Try this. Hope it works. If it not works tell me i gave u better answer